# Cocoa: Middle mouse click event (global) + gesture API?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, gesture, gesture-recognition, shortcut

Are there any resources that might guide me in how to make my app respond to any type of mouse click that is not the left / right button? Globally, even when my app is not active.

And for magic mouse / trackpad, are there any frameworks or resources available to easily attach my code to a specific gesture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find everything related to mouse events:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingMouseEvents/HandlingMouseEvents.html

and trackpad events:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingTouchEvents/HandlingTouchEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH13-SW10

Here is a stack overflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752427/osx-detect-system-wide-keydown-events-solved-with-sample-code) that has explanation for handling global events.

Comment: The problem is I have no NSView or NSWindow, the event can happen in any active application.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752427/osx-detect-system-wide-keydown-events-solved-with-sample-code

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly it, and in the handler I just check [evt buttonNumber] to find the button that I need.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code example based on Shashank's (very helpful) answer.

```
NSEventMask eventMask = NSOtherMouseDownMask|NSOtherMouseUpMask;
[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:eventMask
       handler:^(NSEvent *event) {
           if (event.type == NSOtherMouseDown) {
               NSLog(@"middle click down");
           } else if (event.type == NSOtherMouseUp) {
               NSLog(@"middle click up");
           }
       }];
```