# OSX: Monitoring Event when Mission Control is activated

Tags: macos, events, mouseevent, mission-control

I am trying to listen to Mouse Event and Keyboard Event by attaching global event listener, as describe in [this great thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752427/osx-detect-system-wide-keydown-events-solved-with-sample-code).

However, when Mission Control is called, it seems that it blocks my listeners. I really appreciate any suggestion on how to work around this.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get around this problem by using event taps, which are available in the Carbon [Quartz Event Services Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/index.html).

**Objective-C sample code** (I couldn't get it working in Swift):

Assuming you have defined a C function

```
CGEventRef yourCallbackFunction(CGEventTapProxy proxy, CGEventType type, CGEventRef event, void *userinfo);
```

you can then use this code to listen for the event `SomeEventHere`:

```
CFMachPortRef ref = CGEventTapCreate(kCGHIDEventTap, 
                                     kCGHeadInsertEventTap,
                                     kCGEventTapOptionListenOnly, 
                                     CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventSomeEventHere),
                                     (CGEventTapCallBack)yourCallbackFunction,
                                     userinfo);
CFRunLoopSourceRef src = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, ref, 0);
CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetMain(), src, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
```