# Cocoa App - Get Keyboard Events When Application Not Focused

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm writing a Cocoa app that needs to be able to capture keyboard events even when not focused. (It's controlling another app via the Apple Scripting Bridge).

I have tried the solution here: [OSX: Detect system-wide keyDown events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752427/osx-detect-system-wide-keydown-events-solved-with-sample-code)

It compiles fine, but doesn't actually do anything. I'm putting the code in my init method.

I also can't get CGEventTap to work either. Any suggestions?

Here's my code:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:(NSKeyDownMask) handler:^(NSEvent *event){
    NSLog(@"test");
}];
```

}

Also, I'm aware that assistive devices needs turned on. Unfortunately when I go into the settings it only lists specific apps. Mine isn't one of them.

Comment: did you run your tool as root? have you turned on "support for assistive devices"?

Comment: As of now, yes and yes. I finally figured out how to manually turn accessibility on for the app by dragging it into the security window.

Comment: I think there's API for checking if it's on or not.. you can then prompt the user if it's off. I guessI should write this as an answer?

Comment: I'm aware of the API. It's not the assistive devices or running as root that's the problem. It's still not working even when both those issues are resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Use `AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions` to request access. Then you'll show up in System Preferences.