# Keypresses & Basic Objects, NSView Required?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsevent

So this is the code that I have however it seems oversimplistic to me, which is probably why it isn't catching user keypresses as was my intent of this mini-project:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>


@interface keyObject : NSObject
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent;
@end




@implementation keyObject
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    NSLog(@"keypress detected!");
}

@end


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(@"test");
        keyObject * myObject = [[keyObject alloc] init];
    }
    while (1) {
    // Waiting for event to trigger?
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've read that it's possible to catch user-input without an NSView although maybe this would make it easier? I'd like to create a global hotkey via my own command line program.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following `NSEvent` method:

```
+ (id)addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:(NSEventMask)mask
                                   handler:(NSEvent * _Nullable (^)(NSEvent *))block
```

To monitor key events, you should probably provide `NSKeyDownMask | NSKeyUpMask` as `NSEventMask`.

See [Apple documentation regarding monitoring events](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/MonitoringEvents/MonitoringEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH15-SW3).

[Answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4752427/1689609) may also be useful to you, although they cover system-wide keyDown events instead of your application local ones.

Comment: Ah well I was trying to make it system wide as well actually hehe. Anyways, so would it be possible to implement this in the main()  method?: [NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSKeyDownMask                                            handler:^(NSEvent *event){          // Activate app when pressing cmd+ctrl+alt+T         if([event modifierFlags] == 1835305 && [[event charactersIgnoringModifiers] compare:@"t"] == 0) {                [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];         }     }];

Comment: @Pigman168, you should have no problems with using this approach in `main`. The only point that you will probably need to setup and run `NSRunLoop` instance (and probably setup `NSApplication`) to receive events. `NSApplicationMain(argc, argv)` usually does that setup for you.

Comment: Thank you ever so much! I'll try that out later this evening. My apologies for the (potentially) horrible formatting of my comment, I'm on my phone which is somewhat limited.